# Running jenkins behind proxy, reverse proxy not configured properly

Tags: nginx, jenkins, proxy, glassfish

When running behind proxy (NGINX) I get message

> It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken.

I referred to [this link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy), but still get the same message. It refers to file `/etc/default/jenkins` which is not the case for me as I downloaded the zip file and am running in glassfish.

As I understand all I need is to provide argument `--prefix` to `JENKINS_ARGS`. How do I do that when running in glassfish behind nginx.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess but if you run Jenkins inside of GlassFish I think you have to set the proxy on the GlassFish JVM.

You can either add the following JVM options via the GlassFish admin GUI (`server-config` -> `JVM Settings` -> `JVM Options`):

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostname
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyhostname
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

or you can set them via `asadmin` in the following way:

```
asadmin create-jvm-options -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostname
```

Comment: When I run Jenkins inside GlassFish and access it over 8080 (default port), everything is fine. It is even fine if I use IPTABLE to do a port forwarding `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080`.

I am not able to configure jenkins to run behind nginx. For now I have no nginx running.